# Upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

I bought a Dell XPS 15 almost 4 years ago. It had just 500 GB. So to recover space from recovery partition, I burnt dell recovery on to disks. It took 2 DVDs to burn the recovery image. Then I created ISOs of those DVDs. Finally I formatted recovery partition, that saved me some 10+ GBs. Now I have recovery disks and ISOs. However now my DVD drive is screwed up. It is not functioning well. And I am currently running Ubuntu.

Now that Microsoft made Windows 10 upgrade free, I thought I should get back to the factory Windows 7 by applying recovery and get the licensed Windows 10 by upgrading.

**(1)** But since I am not able to run recovery disks as my four year old DVD drive is not functioning well and

**(2)** I don't know if I can create recovery USB from recovery ISOs, I don't find any way to get back to my old factory Windows 7 and upgrade to Windows 10.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: **(1)** Try using an external optical drive to attempt restore. **(2)** If you're failing to boot and restore the recovery images, grab a Windows 7 iso matching your system's type (home basic, home premium, professional, ultimate) from friends [do not use pirated/cracked ones] and use your product key to activate after installing. The issue is you should reinstall all the drivers and applications from product support at dell.

Comment: By (2) do you mean to imitate factory image manually? Also I am not having product key for my factory Windows 7, though I have OEM partition intact. Is it possible to activate explicitly installed Windows 7 from OEM partition?

Comment: What do you mean by OEM partition, provided you already erased your recovery partition? The product key is printed on a sticker named 'Certification of Authenticity' stuck on bottom of laptop or top/side of PC. Also did you try creating boot able USB from the recovery ISOs you have? Use tools like http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu in Ubuntu? Browse and select the first disc's iso to write to USB. Then repeat the steps for another USB to make the second one from the other iso image(or simply extract the second iso to a new USB using decompression software.)

Comment: Ok turns out that the OEM partition does not contain the anything about the product activation, but contains only the dell diagnostics software. [Here](http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/100997-oem-reserved-partition-what.html) is the thread. Also unsure whether creating USB from ISOs will work smooth, since I guess if I had created USB from Dell's own software that come installed on their factory Win7, it would have created a single USB. Anyways I am having the product key on sticker of my laptop and also downloaded Win7 Home Premium ISO. Should I try that first?

Comment: I would suggest trying the USB method first. If it works, then a lot of time can be saved from installing all the drivers and software. If the USB method works, it will ask for the second disk at the end. So you will need the another USB drive with the contents of second iso extracted to it. Clean installing with the iso you downloaded will require you to download and install drivers from dell support, but if you like to do hands own on this, you can go for using the windows disc:-)

Comment: Fortunately Dell has given me the resource CD containing all the drivers :). So for me that will be easy stuff now. However creating single bootable recovery USB from multiple ISOs and make it work will be interesting task to do. Anyways if clean installation from Windows 7 ISO works well, I mean with both drivers and activation, then I dont see any need for me to even keep those recovery ISOs themselves. Apart from this the factory Windows 7 came installed with a lot of Dell's crapware. I always preferred clean Windows over factory image. Will there be any use of factory Win 7 in that case?

Comment: That's a good news.! For some manufacturers, the special function keys (like increasing&decreasing volume or brightness, muting, turning on or off the wireless etc are usually saved to the recovery disc/partition. In any case you find difficulty in using them, your so created recovery DVDs or their ISOs may be needed. Its a rare case, but keep those discs and images until you get everything as you expected. After installing all those software and when you feel everything sounds well, you must take a backup using your favorite tool (inbuilt or 3rd party)